# Getting cover from flac in iOS with AVFoundation and AudioToolbox

Tags: ios, avfoundation, flac

With the help of [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54006265/3588557), I successfully read metadata from my flac file. It seems however that the metadata is in one block, and the cover image is in a different. With the help of `metaflac --list my.flac`, I've located that there is at least one block with an image. I can't seem to figure out how to extract these.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up doing some very low level metadata block reading by hand, instead of relying on any libs.

My less than pretty solution can be found here: https://github.com/Human-Entertainment/Listen-in-Place/blob/db7dde9195b162dedd976b22f295a9bbd5ab3b14/Listen%20in%20Place/Player.swift#L24-L77, i'm contemplating making a SwiftPM library, for the sole purpose of reading the metadata blocks, but for now, this'll suffice.